# Tab out of input not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input as following

```
<input type="text" id="allSchoolsListText" size="100" style="width: 85%" value="All Colleges and Universities" placeholder="All Colleges and Universities" alt="All Colleges and Universities">
```

it has a click event inside js file

When I press "tab" button the focus comes on html controls in the website, 
but when the focus comes to above mentioned input, then it never goes out even if you press tab n number of times.

Comment: put your javascript code. With the html `<input>` tag we can't know what you're doing

Comment: You need to read [ask], then create MCVE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Created small example on how this can be happen:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("#test");
console.log(input);
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    // Capture the tab keyevent, and make it not do the default behavior.
    if (e.which === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Tab failed");
    };
});
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text">
```

So what you have to do is see if the click event's `handler` has something that catch and prevent the default behavior when press the tab key.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually using e.preventDefault();

Comment: Good catch. In my case the text input (operating as a Mapbox geocoder form) had autocomplete enabled on it, which was capturing tabs/shift+tabs and ignoring them.